# Hide and show data onSubmit event on imported Component

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I would like to hide my data if someone is searching my list items. I have imported my searchbar on Homepage and it seems that the data is not rerendering despite I use a conditional variable with useState.

What I am trying to achieve is the fact that at the beggining the user is seeing the search bar with a list of item. Whenever the user is searching for a string, I want to hide my list of items, as the new data will show. Currently whenever the user is searching does retrieve the search items + initial list of items, which is not ok.

Please find my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client'
import SearchReviews from "./SearchReviews"

const REVIEWS = gql`
  query GetReviews {
    reviews (sort: "createdAt:desc") {
        data{
            ...
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
  }
`

export default function Homepage() {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(REVIEWS)
    const [ show, setShow] = useState(true)

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>
    if (error) return <p>`Error! ${error}`</p>

    // console.log(data)
    return (
        <div>
            <SearchReviews onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault()
                // console.log(e.target[0].value)
                setShow(false). <==================HERE
            }}/>

            {show && (
                <div>
                        {data.reviews.data.map(review => (
                            <div key={review.id} className="review-card">
                                <div className="rating">{review.attributes.rating}</div>
                                <h2>{review.attributes.title}</h2>
                                <h5>{review.attributes.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</h5>

                                {review.attributes.categories.data.map(c => (
                                    <small key={c.id}>{c.attributes.name}</small>
                                ))}

                                <p>{review.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}... </p>
                                <Link to={`/details/${review.id}`}>Read more</Link>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                </div>
                )}
            </div>
    )
}
```

And with SearchReviews.js

```
export default function SearchReviews() {
    const [ first, setFirst ] = useState(false)
    const [ query, setQuery] = useState("")

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(SEARCH, {skip: !first,variables: {my_query: query}})
    if (loading) return <p>Loading data...</p>
    if (error) return <p>`Error! ${error}`</p>
    // console.log(data)
    return (
        <div>

            <div className="wrap">
                <div className="search">
                    <form onSubmit={e => {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        // console.log(e.target[0].value)
                        setQuery(e.target[0].value)
                        setFirst(true)


                    }}>

                        <input type="search"
                               placeholder="Search Malware"
                               className="searchTerm"
                               id="input_text"
                               autoComplete="off"
                                />
                        <br/>
                        {/*<button type="submit" className="searchButton">Submit</button>*/}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            {first && (

            <div className="dataResult">
                    {data.reviews.data.map(review => (
                        <div key={review.id} className="review-card">
                        <div className="rating">{review.attributes.rating}</div>
                        <h2>{review.attributes.title}</h2>
                        <h5>{review.attributes.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</h5>

                        {review.attributes.categories.data.map(c => (
                            <small key={c.id}>{c.attributes.name}</small>
                            ))}

                            <p>{review.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}... </p>
                            <Link to={`/details/${review.id}`}>Read more</Link>
                            </div>
                            ))}

            </div>
                )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Currently the old data is not removed despite the form is submitted, which means that the new state is not re-rendered in the DOM, despite the variable is changed. I think I need to return a boolean value from the child component `<SearchReviews />` to parent and change the state.

I tried event with something like this:

```
    const updateShow = () => {
        setShow(false)
    }

return (
        <div>
            <SearchReviews onChange={updateShow}/>
            <Link to={`/search/`}>Search Library</Link>
            <button> | </button>
            <Link to={`/create`}>Create</Link>
            <button> | </button>
            <Link to={`/new`}>New</Link>
            {show && (
                <div>
                        {data.reviews.data.map(review => (
                            <div key={review.id} className="review-card">
                                <div className="rating">{review.attributes.rating}</div>
                                <h2>{review.attributes.title}</h2>
                                <h5>{review.attributes.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</h5>

                                {review.attributes.categories.data.map(c => (
                                    <small key={c.id}>{c.attributes.name}</small>
                                ))}

                                <p>{review.attributes.body.substring(0, 200)}... </p>
                                <Link to={`/details/${review.id}`}>Read more</Link>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                </div>
                )}
            </div>
    )
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: is  Test() in the example above the same as SearchReviews? If so you are not passing the onSubmit method to the component as props so it wont get called.

Comment: Yes, they are the same. I've updated the code. I need to hide all the Parent list items , after the search's component is made, therefore I don't think that I need to pass the hiding function from parent to Child through the props, as the state in on Parent, not on Child

Comment: Yes but you want to update the parent state during an event on the child component, so you should pass the function down to the child and call it in the onSubmit function of the child. Or just pass setShow down. See my response below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass setShow down to the SearchReviews component as props.

```
export default function SearchReviews({setShow}) {
    const [ first, setFirst ] = useState(false)
    const [ query, setQuery] = useState("")

    // Call the parent function (passed by props) within the child handler
     <form onSubmit={e => {
         e.preventDefault()
         // console.log(e.target[0].value)
         setQuery(e.target[0].value)
         setFirst(true)
         setShow(false)
     }}>
```

Then in the parent component:

```
   <SearchReviews setShow={setShow}/>
```